# problems with java layout manager

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am building small chat program and what I want is to display every message in different side.

For example: my messages in the left side and the other user's messages in the right side.

I wrote this code:

```
public final class ChatPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private javax.swing.JPanel main_panel;

public ChatPanel() {
  main_panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
  main_panel.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(main_panel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  main_panel.setBackground(java.awt.Color.green);
  //add_message("Hello\n\n\nha", true);
  //add_message("Hello", false);
  javax.swing.JScrollPane pane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(main_panel);
  pane.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(433, 213));
  add(pane);
  repaint();
}

public void add_system_message(String message) {
  javax.swing.JTextPane message_area = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
  message_area.setAlignmentX(javax.swing.JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
  javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet center = new javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet();
  javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

  javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet black = new javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet();
  javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.setForeground(black, java.awt.Color.BLACK);

  javax.swing.text.StyledDocument doc = message_area.getStyledDocument();

  try {
     doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), message, black);
     doc.setParagraphAttributes(doc.getLength(), 1, center, false);
  } catch (javax.swing.text.BadLocationException e) {
     System.err.println("ERROR:\n\t" + e.getMessage());
  }
  main_panel.add(message_area);
  main_panel.repaint();
}

public void add_message(String message, boolean is_main_user) {
  javax.swing.JTextArea stam = new javax.swing.JTextArea(message);
  stam.setWrapStyleWord(true);
  stam.setLineWrap(true);
  stam.setEditable(false);
  if (is_main_user) {
     stam.setAlignmentX(javax.swing.JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
  } else {
     stam.setAlignmentX(javax.swing.JLabel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
  }
  stam.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(3, 3, 3, 3, java.awt.Color.red));
  main_panel.add(stam);
  main_panel.repaint();
  repaint();
}
}
```

It works fine when I call `add_message("Hello", false);` in the consructor, but when I call this function from a button (in another panel) it doesn't add the message.

Why does it happen¿

**P.S**
I am usually don't work with layouts managers, only with the netbeans GUI builder.

Comment: You are welcome for the help you got in your last question on this topic in which I suggested you could use attributes in a JTextPane. But you deleted the question without even a simple "thank you" for the help. Follow up questions should be asked in the original question so everybody knows what has been suggested. So I won't bother helping this time, since you will probably just delete the answer again.

Comment: I have wrote thank you in the comment

Comment: I don't see any comment??

Comment: so look again I the only one that wrote a comment

Comment: Your originally deleted the question and just undeleted it. And you just added the comment 11 minutes ago AFTER I made my comment above. And you still haven't "accepted" the answer even thought showed you how to solve the problem.

Comment: one comment above is before more then eleven minutes and I thanked you there!

Comment: The point was you deleted the question, so posting a thank you comment doesn't really show that you read the answer or that it solved the problem not does it?  You normally "accept" the answer when it solves a problem, not delete the question.

Comment: Unless his goal is to convince most folks not to answer any of his future questions.

Comment: But the site is not dumb since deleting questions where answers have been provided increases the risk of being question-banned.

Comment: I have wrote **Thank you** 4 hours ago, and just forgot to accept it. So what????
Shit happens, I have much more important things in my life.

Comment: @sagiziv, `..and just forgot to accept it.` - so now you delete it again? That is your solution? Not only did I give you the solution in your last question, I gave you the proper solution in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add  `main_panel.revalidate();` before the `repaint()` call in order to instruct the Swing layout manager to re-layout newly added components again.

Comment: Thank you very much @tsolakp for the quick answer, it worked☺
Do you know by the way if there is any way I can create some gaps between the added components¿ Thank you again☻

Comment: You can try to add fixed size box strut after adding textfield. Add `main_panel.add( Box.createVerticalStrut(10) );` after `main_panel.add(message_area);`.

Comment: Actually the order should be `revalidate()` (to invoke the layout manager) and then `repaint()` to make sure the components get repainted properly.